# Trying to create a table in javascript using forms to get the number of rows

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table using javascript. The number of rows is inserted by the user using this form.I don't know how to output this table correctly.Tried this but i think i have  a problem inside the javascript code.Can someone please show me how to output a table where the number of rows is inserted in this form?
Here is my code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="table" id="hey">
      Insert nr of rows <input type="text"/>
    </form>

    <script>
     var nr=document.getElementById("hey");
     var c=parseInt("nr");
     for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
         print("<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>");
     }
    </script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need a form. Have a text box with an id and a button. On click of the button, call a function and have your for loop inside that function. Also, i think you're confused between table tag and row tag. Do some more JavaScript before continuing.

Comment: Ok thank you venkatKA but i can't find the problem inside the for loop.I think there is a prob with the print funct inside the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an error in your `for` loop, you had:

```
for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
     print("<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>");
 }
```

This should be:

```
for(i=0;i<c;i++){
    print("<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>");
}
```

---

As for your actual problem, you could try doing it like this:

**HTML**

```
Insert number of rows
<input type="text" id="hey" />
<input type="button" value="Generate table" id="btnShow">
<div id="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    height:50vh;
    width:50vw;
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
//Event listener for the button.
document.getElementById ("btnShow").addEventListener ("click", generateTable, false);
//Function generating the table.
function generateTable() {
    //Get the value the user gave
    var nr = document.getElementById("hey").value;
    //Make it an Int
    var c = parseInt(nr);
    //Get the div containing the table
    var div = document.getElementById("container");
    //Write the table
    div.innerHTML += "<table border='1' id='table'>";
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        //Write the rows and cells
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += "<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr>"
    }
}
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmarLsgL/1/)**

---

**EDIT**

I've updated the code to clear the div before adding rows a second time.

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmarLsgL/2/)**

**JavaSript**

```
//Event listener for the button.
document.getElementById ("btnShow").addEventListener ("click", generateTable, false);
//Function generating the table.
function generateTable() {
    //Get the value the user gave
    var nr = document.getElementById("hey").value;
    //Make it an Int
    var c = parseInt(nr);
    //Get the div containing the table
    var div = document.getElementById("container");
    //Clear the container div                       <----------- Note this
    div.innerHTML = " ";
    //Write the table
    div.innerHTML += "<table border='1' id='table'>";
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        //Write the rows and cells
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += "<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr>"

    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks JsFiddle! This code has a problem when outputting the nr of rows.You can try by yourself.Anyway thanks.I got it.

Comment: @Doggy I don't see any problem in the row output?

Comment: Ok just try first to add 1 row to the table.Up to here everythng is ok.There appears a one row table. Then try  to add 3 rows for example.In the end instead of a table with 3 rows the output is a table with the nr of rows equal to the sum of all tables you added.In this case a table with 4 rows

Answer (score -1):

This is what a proper table should look like.

< table > /*this is the table that will contain all of the rows and table data */

< tr > /* this stands for table row */

< td > /* this stands for table data which is inside the row. You can think of these as columns */

< / td >

< td >

< / td >

< / tr >

< / table >
You do not need all of the extra coding unless you are trying to do something very specific.

Comment: Thanks Plam but i want to take the number of rows as input by the user.That's why i created the form.